# Problem when removing index.php from url

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter

dont worry it is not an another how to remove index.php from url question!! :D

i researched and made according to tutorials; here is my source
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

im sure about all steps, but when run it, i dont see any error message… url changes like

> ```
> www.blablabla.com/contact
> www.blablabla.com/about
> ```

but it always display homepage :/ thats weird!!

what can be problem? any idea?

thanks a lot! appreciate helps!!

Comment: You should post the rewrite rules you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it always displays the home page it could be that your application isn't configured properly.

Check the `system/application/config/config.php` file and find the `$config['uri_protocol']` option.

If you notice, in the comments there are a number of options you can try. I've found that sometimes on different servers I need to try different options before it will work (I think it's something to do with the PHP configuration, the AUTO option doesn't always get it right).

Comment: hmm, i have never thought about that part. thanks for clue! that's currently AUTO

so i will try other options here
| 'AUTO'   Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'  Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING' Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'  Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";

Comment: WOW YOU ARE A LIFE-SAVER!!! thanks a lot!
i changed to "REQUEST_URI" and everything is working well! thanks! : )

Comment: Glad it helped - I had the same issue myself :)